# grabbing dynamic element in a table using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

the link I'm trying to scrape is https://hcad.org/property-search/real-property/real-property-search-by-account-number/

I'm using this method currently

```
driver.get('https://hcad.org/property-search/real-property/real-property-search-by-account-number/')

driver.implicitly_wait(2)        
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/h1').click()

actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB * 2 )
actions.send_keys(account_num)
actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
actions.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    
actions.perform()
```

to type the account number in search box and search it which gives me a new form.
I tried to find the input area using full xpath but it never works.
Is there is anyway I can write account num using element xpath or I can excess the form elements other then actions method.
I tried different methods.
like searching input area using (id,full xpath) using driver implicity wait function but none of them work please help me here so that I can grab elements using your method on the form I get after typing account number I'm lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong locator.
Also, I don't understand why are you using Actions instead of Selenium.send_keys()?
I would do this as following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get('https://hcad.org/property-search/real-property/real-property-search-by-account-number/')

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe")))

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[name="searchval"]'))).send_keys(account_num)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[type="submit"]'))).click()
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the questions were you able to type the random account number in the input field ? as it is showing me selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:  error

Comment: @AliUmer there is an iframe here. You first need to switch to it. see the updated code

Answer (score 0):

The search field is in iframe, you would need to switch the driver focus :

code :

```
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get('https://hcad.org/property-search/real-property/real-property-search-by-account-number/')
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[src='https://public.hcad.org/records/Real.asp']")))
driver.find_element_by_id('acct').send_keys("12345")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[value='Search']"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks it was the iframe. It worked finally